# Move last lines to first line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have high number of txt files in `E:\Desktop\Social_media\edit8\New folder (2)` directory and each file have an arrangement like following:

```
Bolt;539,110
Classmates;263,454
PlanetAll;126,907
theGlobe;73,063
SixDegrees;64,065
JANUARY 1997
```

Now I want to move last lines to first line like following:

```
JANUARY 1997
Bolt;539,110
Classmates;263,454
PlanetAll;126,907
theGlobe;73,063
SixDegrees;64,065
```

I write following python script for this:

```
import os

directory = r'E:\Desktop\Social_media\edit8\New folder (2)'  # Replace with the directory path containing your text files

# Get a list of all text files in the directory
files = [file for file in os.listdir(directory) if file.endswith('.txt')]

# Process each file
for file in files:
    file_path = os.path.join(directory, file)
    
    # Read the file content
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    
    # Extract the last line and strip the newline character
    last_line = lines.pop().strip()
    
    # Insert the last line at the beginning
    lines.insert(0, last_line)
    
    # Write the modified content back to the file
    with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(lines)
```

**My script working good but I don't know why it move last line to first of first line like following:**

```
JANUARY 1997Bolt;539,110
Classmates;263,454
PlanetAll;126,907
theGlobe;73,063
SixDegrees;64,065
```

**Where is my script problem? and how to fix it?**

Comment: The last line doesn't have a line break. Hence, moving it to start of the file works like above. Just add linebreak.

Comment: You need a newline character following the visible text of the last line.

Comment: @VishnudevKrishnadas tnq, please provide modified of script as answer that I learn and accept answer

Comment: Just remove the `strip` function that you are using, the one that has a comment  - "...and strip the newline character".

Comment: Why do you **explicitly** strip the last line's newline if that's not what you want? Did you forget that you wrote that and even commented it saying that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're explicitely removing the newline character with `strip()` (the comments says so). Remove this strip and it should do fine. (`strip` returns a copy of the string with both leading and trailing whitespaces characters removed - [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip))

So instead of

```
# Extract the last line and strip the newline character
last_line = lines.pop().strip()
```

Do

```
# Extract the last line
last_line = lines.pop()
```

If it does not work or if you can't delete the `strip` method because you actually need to remove whitesaces, you can manually add a newline character at the end of the last line by doing like that

```
# Insert the last line at the beginning
lines.insert(0, last_line + '\n')
```